# Low poly to high poly, or high poly to low poly?

Tags: modeling, workflow

Which is easiest to do—make a high poly model and then turn it into a low poly one? Or the other way around?

Comment: Offhand I would say high to low is easier, but a lot also depends on your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

I'ts going to very much depend upon the model. In some cases, adding geometry will be easier, in other cases, removing geometry will be easier. There's not really a "one size fits all" answer to the question. If you're asking about a specific model, edit your question, and provide links to images or blend files.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: from low to high.

A model always start with basic shapes and low polygon objects, so what everybody does is to make a low polygon object and then add details. There is no easy process, it is the only process. Once you finish the project the amount of polygons can be adjusted.

The most important thing is to achieve the maximum amount of detail in the less amount of time.