# Work methodology to get object in different level of details

Tags: workflow, unity

I started to work on my first 3D game. For this purpose I need objects copies with different levels of details. For now I have created a high poly model, and it is quite time consuming task to make it low poly.  I would like to ask about tips how to organize work. Should I work on the low poly models first?

Comment: See the answers here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13968/low-poly-to-high-poly-or-high-poly-to-low-poly